# Can I display GMT on my iPad's world clock?

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iPad running iOS 8.1. Can I include a world clock pane with GMT? I see London as an option, but it appears that it adjusts for DST.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) instead of a city. (Strictly [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) no longer exists.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a answer. If you set the clock for Reykjavík, Iceland, it matched GMT a year round. If any answer can make the clock labeled something more like Greenwich Mean Time or UTC or something like that, I'd prefer such an answer to my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the source of the world clock widget to add UTC (or name it GMT if you prefer).

```
cd /Library/Widgets
sudo vi WorldClock.js
```

Then, in the Europe section, add the line:

```
{city:'UTC', offset:0, timezone:'UTC', id:"2647937"},
```

You may need to remove and recreate any existing clocks in your dashboard for UTC to show up in the list.

Comment: I think this is discussing the World Clock widget in OS X dashboard, not the World Clock screen in the iOS clock app.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, misread the original post. Ran across this post while looking for a fix for OSX, and thought I'd share the answer I found.

Comment: That is a perfect chance to add your own question and answer it, because this will probably help someone else!  And [yes, that's perfectly ok to do](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @AlanShutko - Done: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187931/how-can-i-add-a-utc-world-clock-to-my-osx-dashboard/187932

Comment: @AlanShutko question etiquette-wise: should I now delete this answer/comment thread, or leave it for posterity?

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer my question, but I'm glad you posted it.

Answer (score -3):

Alter GMT to Zulu Time. Zulu time is just an Americanism to avoid the of GMT. It also easier under fire to state 0140 zulu than 0140 GHT

Comment: Not a great Answer. “[Zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)” is just a label for “UTC”. The term comes from the NATO phonetic alphabet word for Z. The term is certainly not an “Americanism” as it is used around the world including in international standards such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). And the term has nothing to do with “avoiding GMT”. Basically this Answer is a duplicate of the [accepted Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153778/17907). I suggest deleting this one. A comment on that Answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: "It also easier under fire to state 0140 zulu than 0140 GHT" Apparently easier than typing "GMT", too.