# How can I add a UTC world clock to my OSX dashboard?

Tags: macos

In the OSX dashboard, the world clock doesn't have a UTC option. Choosing London only works half of the year (the other half London is on Daylight Savings Time and is UTC+1).

I could choose Atlantic/Reykjavik, which is always on UTC, but it seems like a hack, and I'd rather have my clock display "UTC" instead of "Reykjavik".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can edit the source of the world clock widget to add UTC:

```
cd /Library/Widgets
sudo vi WorldClock.js
```

Since Mac OS El Capitan, the file is now found here:

```
cd /Library/Widgets/World Clock.wdgt/
sudo vi WorldClock.js
```

Then, in the Europe section, add the line:

```
{city:'UTC', offset:0, timezone:'UTC', id:"2647937"},
```

The "city" will become the display name of the clock widget; it can be whatever you like.

You may need to remove and recreate any existing clocks in your dashboard for UTC to show up in the list. Since Mac OS Mojave, you will need to kill the DashboardClient process to see the new option (it will restart on its own):

```
killall DashboardClient
```

Comment: This seems like a hack too: UTC shouldn't be a "city".

Comment: Just to update, on Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan, the file `WorldClock.js` is in `/Library/Widgets/World Clock.wdgt/`.

Comment: Just to update, on Sierra UTC already exists. No need to hack.

Comment: @joe-p How did you determine the `id` value or is it made up?

Comment: @Brettski i probably copied/pasted from: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130802094353750

Comment: On Mac OS Mojave, I had kill the DashboardClient process ( $ killall DashboardClient). It restarted on its own. After that, I could see UTC in the clock.

Comment: On Mojave, had to toggle Dashboard off and on again in System Preferences > Mission Control for the script change to take effect, removing all clocks didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 25):

There is already a UTC clock available.

Assuming you're on Yosemite:

1. Go to your notification center
2. Click Edit at the bottom
3. Add the World Clock and click Done.
4. Hover over the World Clock you just added, and click on the (i) icon.
5. Enter UTC when it asks for City.
6. That's it. You're done.

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't figure out these instructions for my High Sierra Machine machine so I installed this [Status Clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/status-clock/id552792489?mt=12) from Pulsely Consulting:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is much better than the built-in clock widgets, because it's always visible and it shows the time in 24h format.